# MySQL Join is ignoring rows with a null email column value

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to accomplish a JOIN of multiple tables in MySQL. I have managed to write the following query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) as name,
    c.title,
    c.department,
    CONCAT(c2.first_name, ' ', c2.last_name) as reports_to,
    c.phone_work,
    c.phone_mobile,
    e.email_address
FROM 
    email_addresses e,
    email_addr_bean_rel eb,
    contacts c
LEFT JOIN
    contacts c2 ON c.reports_to_id = c2.id
WHERE
    c.id = eb.bean_id and
    e.id = eb.email_address_id;
```

This is producing a table with the data I require, the only problem is that this does not include the full list of contacts. When I do a count of the contacts there are 130 however with the above query the results are reduced to 86.

After some investigating I have discovered that this is down to the contacts that do not have an email address being ignored and I don't want this but am not sure how to stop them being ignored if they have a null entry.

The `email_addresses` table contains the email address but to get the `email address` for a `contact` a lookup has to be done in `email_addr_bean_rel` using the `contacts` `id` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',c.first_name,c.last_name) name
     , c.title
     , c.department
     , CONCAT_WS(' ',c2.first_name,c2.last_name) reports_to
     , c.phone_work
     , c.phone_mobile
     , e.email_address
  FROM contacts c
  LEFT 
  JOIN email_addr_bean_rel eb
    ON eb.bean_id = c.id
  LEFT
  JOIN email_addresses e
    ON e.id = eb.email_address_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN contacts c2 
    ON c2.id = c.reports_to_id
```

Comment: This looks a lot better- however when I do a count there are four extra entries than the contacts table holds. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Maybe one contact has multiple email addresses

Comment: Yep, 4 duplicate. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the order of the tables on the join. So, for example, if you want to list all contacts, with or without email, contacts should be your first table. So, I would use the query from JaydipJ, with a small modification:

```
SELECT
 CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) as name,
 c.title,
 c.department,
 CONCAT(c2.first_name, ' ', c2.last_name) as reports_to,
 c.phone_work,
 c.phone_mobile,
 e.email_address
FROM 
 contacts c
 LEFT JOIN  email_addr_bean_rel eb ON c.id = eb.bean_id
 LEFT JOIN  email_addresses e ON e.id = eb.email_address_id
 LEFT JOIN  contacts c2 ON c.reports_to_id = c2.id
```